# Python searching through a txt file for urls

Tags: python

I'm writing lots of urls into a txt file like this inside my script with a loop:

```
fwrite = open('visited.txt', 'a')
fwrite.write('\n{0}'.format(url))
fwrite.close()
```

Then when i re-run later i don't want to process visited links so i do this:(visit is a list of new/old urls)

```
for x in visit:
    if x in open('visited.txt').read().lstrip('\r\n'):
        visit.remove(x)
    else:
        continue
```

But this always skips half of the lines. If there are 1000 urls, it removes only 500 of it. tried both `lstrip`/`rtsrip` with `\n` and `\r\n` but couldn't manage it

Comment: "You are modifying the contents of the object `visit` that you are iterating over when you do `visit.remove(x)`" -- don't do that

Comment: Also, you shouldn't open the visited.txt file, write a line and close it everytime you wish to add a url. Either use 

`with open('visited.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('{0}\n'.format(url))`

or collect all the required urls in a list and write it once to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Python for loop skipping every other loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739407/python-for-loop-skipping-every-other-loop), but for clarity here's a solution for this case:

```
with open('visited.txt') as f:
    visited = f.read().splitlines()

visit = [url for url in visit if url not in visited]
```

By the way, your first snippet is easier with context management, and I rearranged the `\n` since newlines are line *terminators*, not *separators*, especially on Unix-like OS's:

```
with open('visited.txt', 'a') as fwrite:
    fwrite.write('{0}\n'.format(url))
```

Comment: i had to use f.read().sptlilines() but thanks for your answer, it explained a lot

Comment: @ggnoredo Welcome! I forgot `readlines` includes newlines, so I edited that bit.

Answer (score 1):

Read the lines only one time into a list:

```
with open('visited.txt', 'r') as f:
    visited = f.readlines()
```

If you wish to keep only the non visiting, you can convert both lists to sets and subtract one from another, then convert back to list:

```
non_visited = list(set(visit) - set(visited))
```

Comment: still getting the half of it

Comment: I edited my answer which was incorrect, try now.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but that made a totally random list. I mean the list should be in order but this makes it random

Comment: oh, you didn't state this. in this case, @wjandrea answer will work.